# Mining In Remix IDE

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix, mining, mist

Normally in MIST, we have to mine by miner.start() to deploy the smart contract. But in Remix we don't need to mine. Can someone tell me why is that ?

Answer (score 1):

Mist starts a `geth node`, if not already running on your machine. If you are working with main-net, you need to worry about mining. Just send your tx and miners already out there will mine your tx.

But if you are working with private net (setting up your local PoW blockchain). You yourseld need to mine each tx you send. This is irrespective of whether you are using `remix or Mist`.

If you are using `Javascript VM` as your environment in the remix. You need not to worry about mining. But if you are connecting remix to custom `web3`, you need to use same command `miner.start(theradNo)` on your geth to mine the txs.